# Почему появляется ошибка в настройки модуля интеграции СДЭК с Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

При установке модуля Интеграция со СДЭК появилась ошибка
http://joxi.ru/V2VR3GvS0oGbO2 Ошибка пишет, что в системе нет свойства заказа с типом "Местоположение",  я создал такое свойство http://joxi.ru/a2Xan7YTyYpRyA но модуль его не видет. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках магазина в настройках одного из свойств нужно поставить галочку «местоположение».

[image: Пример настройки]